# Quick way to hide objects in render mode?

Tags: rendering

I have a (for my standards) big scene in which I was hiding multiple objects using the eye or viewport symbol. Now I want to render out the scene but as you can imagine I didnt hide the objects for render mode so they will show up in the render :) My question is if there is a fast way to hide all the already hidden objects in render mode without having to go into every subfolder and check if the render symbol is unchecked as this is just very time consuming and frustrating because you will only notice it in the render.

Answer (score 0):

I found this addon, have not tried it, but I think it does the job:
https://trinumedia.gumroad.com/l/sMNjc
Explanation Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfZjGRey_X4

I wish I knew earlier that something like this exists. I've also had a lot of trouble with hidden objects which I forget to disable in render

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small Python script. These little things seem like a good place to start with Python. It's quite easy, flexible and powerful.

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.hide_get() or o.hide_viewport:
        o.hide_render = True
```

You would need to paste in a new text block in the Text editor and hit run:

[image]